# Did I give access to my user folder by mistake?[Windows 7]

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing, users

I shared a folder from my user in Windows 7.

I want to understand if this led to sharing the whole user folder.

This is the description of the issue:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660257(v=ws.10).aspx

As soon as I've discovered it, I've tried to check from a colleague, but the Users folder appeared as empty, without any subfolders.

I'm still wondering if someone could have had access to my Desktop folder.

Comment: Is this a domain joined computer?

Comment: yes it is a domain joined computer.